# The constructor BigInteger(long) is not visible

Tags: java

So I'm creating a factorial program using BigInteger class. But I keep getting the above error.

```
public static BigInteger fact(long n){
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
            result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(i));
        }
        return result;
}
```

I already found the fix which is just add an empty string with result.

`result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""))`

My question is, why do we have to add that empty string ?

Comment: Why do you have a `long` as your parameter, an `int` as you loop variable, and a `BigInteger` to multiply by? The limiting factor here is the loop variable (an `int`), so the others might as well be `int`s too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per oracle docs, [**BigInteger**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) does not have any constructor that takes int as an argument

Secondly you should use `BigInteger.valueOf(i);` instead of `new BigInteger(i + "")`

Answer (score 2):

It is showing the correct error. If you look at [the `BigInteger` class in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), then you can see that there is no constructor that accepts an `int`. So you can't create BigInteger object by using `new` and passing an `int`.

There is a constructor that accepts a string, and by adding an empty string, you are casting your int to string.

You can use the following code:

```
int myint = 5; // For example
BigInteger myBigInter = BigInteger.valueOf(myint);
```

Answer (score 2):

BigInteger constructor with long is private because the library developer wants you to invoke `BigInteger.valueOf(long l)`. The reason why constructor is private is provided in javadoc of valueOf,

> Returns a BigInteger whose value is equal to that of the specified
>   {@code long}.  This "static factory method" is provided in preference
>   to a ({@code long}) constructor because it allows for reuse of
>   frequently used BigIntegers.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an empty string to your constructor parameter, the java compiler transform your parameter to string : 5 + "" -> "5". the resulting consequence is java will use the BigInterger constructor with String parameter. This is why your code works.

```java
 /**
     * Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a
     * BigInteger.  The String representation consists of an optional minus
     * sign followed by a sequence of one or more decimal digits.  The
     * character-to-digit mapping is provided by {@code Character.digit}.
     * The String may not contain any extraneous characters (whitespace, for
     * example).
     *
     * @param val decimal String representation of BigInteger.
     * @throws NumberFormatException {@code val} is not a valid representation
     *         of a BigInteger.
     * @see    Character#digit
     */
    public BigInteger(String val) {
        this(val, 10);
    }
```

So to use a clean code use this :

```
new BigInteger(Integer.toString(i), 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

`123+""` is same as `Integer.toString(123)+""` i.e adding an empty string to an integer is converting that integer to string.

And as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) BigInteger has a constructor that takes the decimal string of an integer as an argument.

And as mentioned by SpringLearner BigInteger doesn't have a constructor that takes just `int` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` has no constructor that accepts `int`.
By adding an empty string, `i` is converted to a `String`.

You could also do something like `new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i))`

Edit:
Why do you have to use a `String`?
`BigInteger` is (usually) used if you need bigger values than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or even `Long.MAX_VALUE`. So, if you want to create a `BigInteger` that holds a value greater than that, you need to pass it as an object/variable that can hold that value. And a `String` is able to hold it.